# My video (.mkv) thumbnails are green (or monochromatic)?

Tags: antergos, thumbnails

[My video (.mkv) thumbnails are green (or monochromatic)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907607/my-video-mkv-thumbnails-are-green-or-monochromatic/910214#910214) Ask Ubuntu link

The question posted above show cases the exact same situation that I'm facing right now, but answers over there do not work on [Antergos](https://antergos.com/), for starters how do I even enable Multiverse and Universe?

---

The situation is that thumbnails created by .mkv files are green in colour but video colours aren't affected by this issue. it seems like a problem with new Nautilus update rather than Ubuntu or Antergos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know `ffmpeg` and `ffmpegthumbnailer` are already Installed in Antergos installation but if not then note than installation process on Ubuntu and Antergos is pretty different.

---

#### This answer is based on Another answer posted by [Elder Geek](https://askubuntu.com/users/225694/elder-geek), this just makes it easy for new users to execute

#### Install ffmpeg

open **Add/Remove software** app and make sure that  `ffmpeg` and `ffmpegthumbnailer` are installed by searchin them, if not then install these packages

[image]

*From here it should be pretty similar to linked answer*

#### **Change the job of creating thumbnails from Totem to ffmpeg**

```
sudo nano /usr/share/thumbnailers/totem.thumbnailer
```

a text file will open up, replace all the text inside it with the following

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=ffmpegthumbnailer
Exec=ffmpegthumbnailer -s %s -i %i -o %o -c png -f -t 10
MimeType=application/mxf;application/ogg;application/ram;application/sdp;application/vnd.ms-wpl;application/vnd.rn-realmedia;application/x-extension-m4a;application/x-extension-mp4;application/x-flash-video;application/x-matroska;application/x-netshow-channel;application/x-ogg;application/x-quicktimeplayer;application/x-shorten;image/vnd.rn-realpix;image/x-pict;misc/ultravox;text/x-google-video-pointer;video/3gpp;video/dv;video/fli;video/flv;video/mp2t;video/mp4;video/mp4v-es;video/mpeg;video/msvideo;video/ogg;video/quicktime;video/vivo;video/vnd.divx;video/vnd.rn-realvideo;video/vnd.vivo;video/webm;video/x-anim;video/x-avi;video/x-flc;video/x-fli;video/x-flic;video/x-flv;video/x-m4v;video/x-matroska;video/x-mpeg;video/x-ms-asf;video/x-ms-asx;video/x-msvideo;video/x-ms-wm;video/x-ms-wmv;video/x-ms-wmx;video/x-ms-wvx;video/x-nsv;video/x-ogm+ogg;video/x-theora+ogg;video/x-totem-stream;audio/x-pn-realaudio;audio/3gpp;audio/ac3;audio/AMR;audio/AMR-WB;audio/basic;audio/midi;audio/mp2;audio/mp4;audio/mpeg;audio/ogg;audio/prs.sid;audio/vnd.rn-realaudio;audio/x-aiff;audio/x-ape;audio/x-flac;audio/x-gsm;audio/x-it;audio/x-m4a;audio/x-matroska;audio/x-mod;audio/x-mp3;audio/x-mpeg;audio/x-ms-asf;audio/x-ms-asx;audio/x-ms-wax;audio/x-ms-wma;audio/x-musepack;audio/x-pn-aiff;audio/x-pn-au;audio/x-pn-wav;audio/x-pn-windows-acm;audio/x-realaudio;audio/x-real-audio;audio/x-sbc;audio/x-speex;audio/x-tta;audio/x-wav;audio/x-wavpack;audio/x-vorbis;audio/x-vorbis+ogg;audio/x-xm;application/x-flac;
```

To save updated file in Nano press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and then type *y* and enter. https://askubuntu.com/questions/54221/how-to-edit-files-in-a-terminal-with-nano

*You can use other text editing apps to edit `/usr/share/thumbnailers/totem.thumbnailer` file if you're not comfortable using nano*

and the restart nautilus

```
nautilus -q
```

#### **Clear all the thumbnails again and check if you're problem is solved**

```
rm -r ~/.cache/thumbnails
```

The command above will clear all the thumbnails again, go check them, they will not be monochromatic now